# Magento textfield maximal field length (5 character)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

I have a magento store.

I have a textfield on every article site (http://www.lettershop.it/de/din-l-mailing-13.html):

"Anzahl"

How can I do that the field length is maximal 5 character?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the html attribute `maxlength="5"` to the input tag.

This can be manipulated with browser tool, but nobody will probably do this.
But if you want to be 100% sure, you also have to check it serverside with PHP.
You will need an observer for this.

Edit:

To add maxlength attribute to custom options field:

Copy

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml`

to

`app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml`

Search for `<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" ... />`

and change this to

`<input type="text" maxlength="5" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" ... />`

This will add maxlength to all custom options of input type text. If you want this for only specific custom input text fields, use if/else logic within template file.

Comment: In html no problem. But how i can do this in magento?